# Reloading the page after selecting images with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to reload the page after I've selected all images. I know that I have a mistake in the code, but I don't know where. 
The variable is Num.
I use more than one jquery library, HTML, CSS and JS.

Files:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.event.drop-2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="colors.js"></script>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function($)
    {
    var num=0;  


    $('.move')
        .click(function(){
                $( this ).toggleClass("selected");
            })

        .drag("init",function(){
          if ( $( this ).is('.selected') ){
                 if (num == 5){
                    alert ("Warning.");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
          num++;
                return $('.selected');

                }
            })

          .drag(function( ev, dd ){
               $( this ).css({
                    top: dd.offsetY,
                    left: dd.offsetX
               });


           });


    });
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Hi</h1>

<div class="move" style="left:300px;"></div>
<div class="move" style="left:450px;"></div>
<div class="move" style="left:600px;"></div>
<div class="move" style="left:750px;"></div>
<div class="move" style="left:900px;"></div>
```

Here is the view of the page:
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/dwkbn/embedded/result/)

Comment: `I need after mark all images to reload the page`. What mark? / Who is Mark?

Comment: Be specific. What's the problem you're having? Dumping a bunch of code into your post and saying "it doesn't work" is not very helpful.

Comment: Also you start your script in a strange way: `$(document).ready(function($) {` should simply be `$(document).ready(function() {` or even better (not really better but shorter and I'm lazy :)) `$(function() {`

Comment: I think he means "after I select (.select) all images"

Comment: Right, i dont know very well English language, but yes. After I select

Comment: @user1006959: Can you please setup a demo on http://jsfiddle.net for us to check out. And please only add the relevant code to the demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dwkbn/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$('.posun').click(function(){
    $( this ).toggleClass("vybrate");
    if($('.vybrate').length === 5){
        window.location.reload()
    }
})
```

`$('.vybrate').length === 5` is simply checking to see if there are 5 elements with the class `.vybrate`. If there are, then we know every one has been selected, so we refresh the page.